# What does "track" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wonder if it means "session" or "area" here:

"U.S. investors are beginning to notice. The J.P. Morgan conference has an entire **track** dedicated to China-based health-care companies at the conference. And last year, Chinese firms announced or completed about $8 billion in cross-border acquisitions, according to data compiled by Bloomberg."

Source: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-01-10/china-investors-have-money-want-biotech-and-don-t-fear-trump

Comment: Should be session.

Comment: "set  of sessions"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually at a conference there are several "streams" or "tracks" which are consist of a related "theme".  The meetings in the "track" you mention would be full of information on Chinese health care companies.  There may be another "track" for energy companies. etc.

Each of the columns might be considered a "track".

[image]